# Removing empty last page space, tab from Google document using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Removing empty last page space, tab from Google document using Google Apps Script

hello, I am new to Script

I often have documents containing several pages with spaces and tabs after copy / paste

I'm trying to erase everything behind the last character entered to print without having to select the number of pages

I only need the first page to print

Can you give me the lead?

The tanaikech script does not work for my use ... Too bad

https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/01/17/deleting-last-empty-page-of-google-document-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: Can you please clarify what's the difference between the situation described in the link you provided and the one you're currently facing? If it's the same, can you please provide more details about `does not work for my use`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tanaike's script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/01/17/deleting-last-empty-page-of-google-document-using-google-apps-script/) removes only one last paragraph and it removes it without of checking if the paragraph is empty.

If you want to remove all empty paragraphs at the end of a doc you can do it this way (beware, it makes call to API for every empty paragraph, see my updated version):

```
function main() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var id = doc.getId();

  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  var pgfs = text.split('\n');

  while(pgfs.pop().replace(/\s+/,"") == "") remove_last_pgf(id);
}


// original Tanaike's script goes here

function remove_last_pgf(docId) {
  var c = Docs.Documents.get(docId, {
  fields: "body.content"
    }).body.content.pop();
      Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(
      {
        requests: [
          {
            deleteContentRange: {
              range: { startIndex: c.startIndex - 1, endIndex: c.endIndex - 1 }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      docId
    );
}
```

Don't forget to add [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) in Services of Script Editor:

[image]

---

### Update

I've refined the script a little bit further:

```
function main() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docId = doc.getId();
  var empty_tail = doc.getBody().getText().search(/\s+$/) + 1;
  if (empty_tail == 0) return; // prevent the error for empty docs
  
  var content = Docs.Documents.get(docId,{fields: "body.content"}).body.content.pop();

  var range = { startIndex: empty_tail, endIndex: content.endIndex-1 };
  var req = { deleteContentRange: { range } };

  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate( {requests: [req] }, docId );
}
```

Now it should work faster since it doesn't call API for every empty line. It gets the position where the empty characters `\s+` start and removes them all with one call to API.

Comment: Thanks a lot #Yuri Khristich for help me
but after 30 minutes i obtain this message after debug 

17:34:45 Erreur 
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.get failed with error: Google Docs API has not been used in project 127214624022 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/docs.googleapis.com/overview?project=127214624022 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
remove_last_pgf @ delete.gs:15
main @ delete.gs:8

Comment: Probably it happened exactly because of too many calls to API. Try my updated version of the script (after a few minutes), it should work better.

Comment: Thanks very much it's Work now  , Perfect

Comment: #Yuri Khristich ,I Obtain this error message when there is nothing to erase. how to pass through this problem ?

Comment: Try to add after the line `var empty tail = ...` the line `if (empty_tail == 0) return;`

Comment: Perfect Mr Yuri Khristich  !! it's Work

Answer (score 0):

I Obtain this error message when there is nothing to erase.
how to pass through this problem ?

[image: Error Appscript]

Answer (score 0):

```
function main() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docId = doc.getId();
  var empty_tail = doc.getBody().getText().search(/\s+$/) + 1;
  
  var content = Docs.Documents.get(docId,{fields: 
  "body.content"}).body.content.pop();
  if (empty_tail == 0) return;
  var range = { startIndex: empty_tail, endIndex: content.endIndex-1 };
  var req = { deleteContentRange: { range } };
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate( {requests: [req] }, docId );
}
```