# How to find and replace special characters in Google Doc using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to replace certain sets of characters in a Google Doc with others. I'm new to Javascript so I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, but here's the code I've been using: old_characters is what's in the Doc and new_characters is what I'm replacing them with, and I've capped the loop at 40 because that's the max number of times I need to do it in the doc.

```
const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
const body = doc.getBody();

var z = 1

while (z < 41) {
    body.findText(old_characters)
      .getElement()
      .asText()
      .setText(new_characters)
  z++
}
  doc.saveAndClose
```

It works fine for some sets of characters, like changing " AM" (from 5 AM) to "am" (to 5am). But I run into issues when trying to change ".." into "." or ":00" into "" (to get rid of double periods, and change times from 5:00 AM to 5am). Nothing happens.

I've used ".." and regex /.{2}/ to identify the double period, for example, and try to replace with "." but they aren't replaced.

I'd also like to delete a bunch of empty space from the end of the document, without deleting the occasional empty line earlier in the doc, and not sure how.

Comment: Search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs%2bregex?tab=Frequent

Comment: As for the empty space at the end of the document, here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020174/14265469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you could make the changes with this code:

```
function main() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  var old_characters = 'AM';
  var new_characters = 'am';
  doc.replaceText(old_characters, new_characters);

  old_characters = '\\.\\.';
  new_characters = '.';
  doc.replaceText(old_characters, new_characters);

  old_characters = ':00';
  new_characters = '';
  doc.replaceText(old_characters, new_characters);
}
```

Or the same algorithm in more fancy style:

```
function main() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  const replaces = [
    {what: 'AM',     to: 'am'},
    {what: '\\.\\.', to: '.'},
    {what: ':00',    to: ''},
  ]

  replaces.forEach(replace => doc.replaceText(replace.what, replace.to));
}
```

- [replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String))

Comment: Why didn't it work for OP? Why is this code the answer?

Comment: @TheMaster probably the main problem was with the dots. For this case one have to use `\\.\\.`. Not `..`, or `/.{2}/`. Not even `\.\.`. I have no idea why the ':00' didn't work, though. Perhaps it was just a next step and after dots, so OP got wrong result.

Comment: Great.  Such info would add value to this answer..

Comment: Thank you! With the double backslash it works. I had actually used replaceText earlier but with just one backslash before the dots, it seemed to replace every character with a dot. I'm having trouble with removing the empty space, but I'll comment on that post instead.

Comment: Actually removing empty space is a quite different matter. It would be better if you make a new question instead (if that solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020174/14265469 doesn't work)