# search and replace in various brackets, script on google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

**The script:** [How to find and replace special characters in Google Doc using Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72961095/how-to-find-and-replace-special-characters-in-google-doc-using-apps-script)

```
function main() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  const replaces = [
    {what: 'AM',     to: 'am'},
    {what: '\\.\\.', to: '.'},
    {what: ':00',    to: ''},
  ]

  replaces.forEach(replace => doc.replaceText(replace.what, replace.to));
}
```

**Hello or looked at its script, the second version because new app script does not accept var. My problem is more complicated, but I can't find a solution, I'm not an expert and I can't speak English, I only know technical cse. On word I had created macros and I wanted to be able to use them on doc google with app script maybe with execution of manual triggers. The first is I need to look for all the string in the docs, which has both letters symbols etc, and is located between linettes, and replace the linettes with corporals, without touching the internal text former:

1
EX:"un’indagine veloce’ 345a qualcosa di più 44 sostanziale, come ‘facciamo un’indagine seria"

Resukt: «un’indagine veloce’ 345a qualcosa di più 44 sostanziale, come ‘facciamo un’indagine seria’»**

**2
Select all words ll inside a list, and convert them to italics**

**3**

```
maiusinz Macro
' Dim strText As String
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="[A-Z]{2;}", MatchWildcards:=True, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop) = True
        With Selection
            strText = Left(.Range.Text, 1) & LCase(Mid(.Range.Text, 2))
            .Range.Text = strText
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .MoveRight wdCharacter, 1, False
        End With
```

**the third operation, I also attach vba scheme of word, and to find the words in round brackets and change the first letter to uppercase EX: (PDA) to (Pda)
the text in parentheses is not fixed can be any
if you can help me I'm grateful**
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like this:

```
function main() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  // main
  fix_quotemarks();
  fix_cases(['PDA', 'AAA', 'BBB']);
  set_italics(['qualcosa','seria']);

  // functions
  function fix_quotemarks() {
    const replaces = [
      {what: '“',  to: '«'},  // <-- updated line
      {what: '”',  to: '»'},  // <-- updated line
      {what: '"',  to: '»'},
      {what: ' »', to: ' «'},
      {what: '^»', to: '«'},
    ]
    replaces.forEach(replace => doc.replaceText(replace.what, replace.to));
  }

  function fix_cases(words) {
    words.forEach(r => doc.replaceText(r, r[0]+r.slice(1).toLowerCase()));
  }

  function set_italics(words) {
    var style = { [DocumentApp.Attribute.ITALIC]: true };
    var pgfs  = doc.getParagraphs();

    for (var word of words) for (var pgf of pgfs) {
      var location = pgf.findText(word);
      if (!location) continue;
      var start = location.getStartOffset();
      var end = location.getEndOffsetInclusive();
      location.getElement().setAttributes(start, end, style);
    }
  }
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Update (changed)**

Here is the new function to convert case `(AAA) --> (Aaa)` for any text inside the brackets:

```
function fix_cases_for_any_text_in_brackets() {
  var doc   = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body  = doc.getBody();
  var words = body.getText().match(/\(.+?\)/g) || [];
  words = [...new Set(words)]; // remove duplicates

  var replaces = words.map(r => ({
    what: '\\(' + r.slice(1,-1) + '\\)',
    to: '(' + r[1].toUpperCase() + r.slice(2,-1).toLowerCase() + ')',
  }));
  
  replaces.forEach(replace => body.replaceText(replace.what, replace.to));
}
```

**Update 2***

Here is the function to convert all th 'AllCaps' words: `AAAA --> Aaaa`:

```
function fix_AllCaps() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var words = body.getText().match(/[A-Z]{2,10}/g) || [];
  words = [...new Set(words)]; // remove duplicates

  var replaces = words.map(r => ({
    what: r,
    to: r[0].toUpperCase() + r.slice(1).toLowerCase(),
  }));

  console.log(replaces);
  
  replaces.forEach(replace => body.replaceText(replace.what, replace.to));
}
```

Comment: “d it’s past time for real accountability,” Thanks I tried, then, the italic words are ok for the corporals I need first to convert the English linettes into the straight ones, then I can convert them into corporals. I put an example of the English linettes. The function of the first capital letter between the round brackets works, if you know the words, but the words inside the brackets can be any, I can not choose them

Comment: const replaces = [
      {what: '“',  to: '"'},
      {what: '”',  to: '"'},
      {what: '"',  to: '»'},
      {what: ' »', to: ' «'},
      {what: '^»', to: '«'},  here with the corporals I finally solved

Comment: I just added the new function to convert case inside the brackets.

Comment: You shall no run this function as a separate function. You have to replace the old function `fix_cases()` inside the `main()` function with this new function. If you want to run it separately you have to add the line `const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();` inside.

Comment: sorok I succeeded, but it does not work well, I reduce lowercase the capital words even outside the round brackets, and only the first word in round brackets comes out right with the first initial capitalization,ry I put my code in your answer because it did not enter the comments. once inserted the last function does not go. all the others work :refult: (Fgh) (tyuioi) (dd)  rrr yyyyv gt

Comment: Well, there were problems. I just rewrote the function `fix_cases_for_any_text_in_brackets()` try it now.

Comment: hello, then last script works thanks, I wanted to use it also to search in the text in the text all the capitalized words both in and out of parentheses, and that become with the first uppercase and lowercase rest I had tried to put this'[A-Z]{2, 10}' instead of search string but it tells me no corresponding. how can I do?  EX:  hello HELLO  and peace (HELLO) over (OVER) PIL > Result: hello Gello and peace (Hello)  over (Over) Pil  Thaks the words are not of your choice but any as in the last function

Comment: `hello Gello`? do you mean `hello Hello`?

Comment: A just added the new function to convert AllCaps words.

Comment: Thank you so much everything works perfectly now. Thank you for teaching me to understand this language on docs, before I had done only for google sheets. Thank you again and congratulations for your experience :-)

Comment: Actually I'm not an expert in Google Docs as well. I play with Google Spreadsheets mostly, too. )