# What are the options for launching a script app, without running it from the editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-experiments

I saw some examples, but I could not understand how they work and how to add the script to be launched on Google Doc. I would like to be able to launch the script of a personal function, without having to enter the editor and click run. As it will be shared with colleagues, I would like to avoid that by mistake they delete the data from the script. Are there any alternatives? It would be to put the startup in the sidebar or in the menu. And also an explanation of how the operation takes place, and how to connect the script.

Comment: Why wouldn't use a custom menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a sidebar it can be done this way:

Make two files in Script Editor: 'Code.gs' and 'sidebar.html'

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('️ Scripts')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'launchSideBar')
  .addToUi()
}

function launchSideBar() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar').setTitle('Sidebar Title'))
}

function hello() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Hello!'); // just an example, you can put your code here
}
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Hello" onClick="google.script.run.hello();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

After reload the document it will give the menu 'Scripts' and command 'Show sidebar'

[image]

After click on the command it will show the sidebar with the button 'Hello'

[image]

Button `Hello` will run the function `hello()`.

**Update**

But actually, since you have to make a custom menu to show the sidebar anyway, it makes sense don't use a sidebar at all and use a custom menu only.

In this case you don't need the file 'sidebar.html' and your 'Code.gs' will look like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('️ Scripts')
  .addItem('Hello', 'hello')
  .addItem('Bye-bye', 'bye')
  .addToUi()
}

function hello() {
  // just an example, you can put any code here
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Hello!'); 
}

function bye() {
  // just an example, you can put any code here
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Bye!'); 
}

// etc
```

It will get you the menu 'Scripts' with the commands 'Hello' and 'Bye-bye' that run the functions `hello()` and `bye()` respectively.

Comment: hello in effect idea was that, I had seen an example.,to me I wanted to connect the main scrip of the other day, which starts by clicking on the sidebar extensions. to run the script on sheets, I just had to create an image and connect the script to be launched, but on doc there is no

Comment: Sorry I failed to understand what do you want. Can you add a couple of screenshots? Do you want to run Google Spreadsheets script from from Google Docs? I'm afraid it's impossible.

Comment: You can make a script in Google Docs that will 'open' (open on the server, not in the browser) a spreadsheet and make some changes or take some info from the spreadsheet.

Comment: I simply try to launch this script without going into editor. On docs they say that you need to create an extension similar to the one you posted with hello. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081717/search-and-replace-in-various-brackets-script-on-google-docs

Comment: To launch a script you have three options: 1) run from Script Editor, 2) run from a custom menu, 3) run from a sidebar. No need any extensions. If you want to make an Add-on which can be installed from Marketplace it's a whole nother story.

Comment: thanks yes that's what I meant, the other two options. how do I create them? if instead of function hello, I put the function of the link performs it?

Comment: Try to change the function `hello()` with your function. If you want to change the name `hello` to something else, make sure you change it in the `sidebar.html` as well.

Comment: Thanks the pom at home I try, it's nice to learn new things :-) makes life less boring. One thing, they closed the question to me, but I don't understand what is wrong with it, does anyone know how I should rephrase it to reopen it? grazieon I know if the automatic translator wrote something wrong in the question :-(

Comment: Alas, in this particular case I don't know it, as well. The question looks more or less legit. Yes, the question is about basics. Probably some local forget that they weren't born with basic knowledge about Google Apps.

Comment: Hello thanks, both excellent, nice to discover new things and how they work, especially for novices the basics are important anyway. Except that sometimes you spend hours searching on google, but without finding the answer. I have serious vision problems, so I struggle a little harder :-) What I was looking for was your update, the simple thing to run the script. Thanks again. The rest learned can be useful, from different perspectives :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yuri's solution shows some of the basics of using a sidebar.  I've expaned on that to show how to access text within the Google Doc.

I'm using templated HTML to seperate HTML from CSS from javascript.  Notice in the HTML_SideBar.html file the use of the `include` commands.  This pulls different files together to form the entire page and then using html.evaluate() later the page is ready to display.

First you need the sidebar.

**HTML_SideBar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS_SideBar'); ?>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="testInput" type="text"><br>
    <input id="insertText" type="button" value="Insert Text" onclick="insertTextOnClick()"><br>
    <input id="getText" type="button" value="Get Text" onclick="getTextOnClick()">
    <?!= include('JS_SideBar'); ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Next is the

**CSS_Sidebar.html**

```
<style>
  input {
    font-size: large;
  }
</style>
```

Then there is the javascript used by the HTML page

**JS_SideBar.html**

```
<script>
  function insertTextOnClick() {
    try {
      let text = document.getElementById("testInput").value;
      google.script.run.insertText(text);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert("Error in insert text: "+err);
    }
  }
  function getTextOnClick() {
    try {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
        function(text) {
          document.getElementById("testInput").value = text;
        }
      ).getText();
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert("Error in get text: "+err);
    }
  }
</script>
```

All of this requires the server side code to display the sidebar and interact with the document from the client (browser).

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  let ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  let menu = ui.createMenu("Side Bar");
  menu.addItem("Show SideBar","showSideBar");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function showSideBar() {
  try {
    let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_SideBar");
    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate());
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in showSideBar: "+err);
  }
}

function insertText(text) {
  try {
    let cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
    if (cursor) {
      // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If the insertion returns null, the cursor's
      // containing element doesn't allow insertions, so show the user an error message.
      let element = cursor.insertText(text);
      if( !element ) {
        DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text here.');
      }
    }
    else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor.');
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in insertText: "+err);
  }
}

function getText() {
  try {
    var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
    // If nothing is selected show the user an error message
    if (selection) {
      let text = "";
      var rangeElements = selection.getRangeElements();
      rangeElements.forEach( rangeElement => {
          let element = rangeElement.getElement().asText().getText()
          text = text+element;
        }
      )
      return text;
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Nothing is selected.');
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in getText: "+err);
  }
}
```

If you try to run this from the menu item it will expect you to authorize the use of the various Google services involved in the process.

Follow these steps to authorize the script.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Refernces**

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Document.getCursor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getCursor())
- [Document.getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getSelection())

Comment: i I tried them both, really great, what you can do, thanks for your patience and guidance.
In my case, that simple script that Yuri put in was enough, but his can come back anyway useful for more now that you understand how it works thanks